# memset() to initialize object in constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, memset

I found this piece of C++ code that uses memset() to initialize an object:

```
struct Message
{
   Message()
   {
      memset(this, 0, sizeof(Message));
   }

   unsigned int a, b, c;
};
```

Since this is a POD structure, this code should be fine.
Is there any advantage in using memset instead of a constructor such as:

```
Message() : a(0), b(0), c(0) {}
```

Comment: Consider what happens if your object has virtual table pointer. Good compiler will most probably determine that you have POD and `memset` them or something like this in second case. But if will decide later to build a hierarchy, you done goofed.

Comment: If you add new field, it will automatically be set to 0, no extra work needed. That's the only advantage I see.

Comment: At least insert a `static_assert` right before/after the memset. This tells both the human reader as well as the compiler that you assume Message to be a POD; the compiler will fail if it isn't, and the reader will know why you think memset would be ok.

Comment: @leemes: Something like `static_assert(std::is_pod<Message>::value);`. But with a non-trivial default constructor it will never be a POD, isn't it? Maybe it should check for a standard layout type?

Comment: I highly doubt it, `memset` should enforce a call to memory, which won't be optimized out, as it will be considered having side effects. Declaring initial values statically gives more options for compiler to optimize.

Comment: @rodrigo Exactly. But with a message as the second argument (before C++17).

Comment: @luk32 While this is most likely true, don't only think about performance (I know, C++ people sometimes are very obsessed with that). Ivan pointed out a nice non-performance advantage.

Comment: @leemes: Then I'd settle with: `static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<Message::value, "class is not memsettable")`

Comment: @rodrigo I guess you're right; standard layout is the thing we're looking for, not POD.

Comment: Another note: POD types can be zero-initialized with value-initialization (empty paranthesis) like `Message x = Message();`, however, this doesn't prevent `Message x;` to be written, in which case it is uninitialized. But that's simply how PODs work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no advantage in using `memset()` like this. Leaving behind all the obvious disadvantages and future pain, there is one disadvantage that makes it less efficient than

```
Message() : a(0), b(0), c(0) {}
```

This is because `POD`s are usually stored in arrays. So good (smart) compiler will have an advantage to replace initialization of multiple objects in an array with a single `memset()`, in case of

```
Message * messages_1 = new Message[100];
```

Or

```
std::vector<Message> messages_2;
messages_2.resize(100);
```

Even when only single object is being constructed, good compiler will use `memset()`, behind the curtain.

Comment: The memset approach does have one advantage for having deterministic 0-values in the _padding bytes_.  Sometimes that matters, perhaps for a hash function that reads it as a blob of data, rather than as an object.

Answer (score 5):

Note that in C++11 and newer you have a nicer option than either of those:

```
struct Message
{
   unsigned int a = 0;
   unsigned int b = 0;
   unsigned int c = 0;
};
```

This should produce identical code (and optimisation opportunities) to the constructor-with-initialisation-list approach while:

- Using less code.
- Being more readable.
- Removing the need to worry about updating initialisation list when members are added.
- Removing the need to think about what to do if `b` needs to default to `-1` later.

Answer (score 1):

The "memset approach" has two advantages over initializers for structures which are large but simple collections of data: It is clearer and has better maintainability.

- *Clearer* because it is obvious and easily verifiable what happens. With single initializations, a reviewer must verify that no member is omitted. (A good compiler called with a sufficiently high warning setting will warn, but in a large project warnings easily drown in the noise.)
- *Better to maintain* because the code stays correct even if a member is added.